# Kafka connector performance. merge topics in kafka vs merge topics in database?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I'm working on a scenario where I want a many-to-one relationship between topics being written to vs the database tables which get written to. Data sources provide messages to topics, and I'm trying to figure out if it makes more sense to try merging the topics in kafka with something like streams before taking the output of that merge and dumping it through a jdbc sink connector, or if it makes more sense to just use the jdbc sink connectors to do the merge and have the mapping implicit in the collection of connectors.

Eg. Topics A,B,C go to table 1, topics D,E,F to table 2, etc.
Scenario 1: use something like streams to merge A,B,C into ABC and use one jdbc sink to dump it to table 1.
Scenario 2: use individual jdbc connectors for A, B, and C, where all 3 connectors dump to table 1.

Performance-wise and resource-wise, is one or the other more likely to choke if I tried to ramp this up to a billion topics?

Comment: If A,B,C all have the same schema, then why bother using streams?

Comment: Don't know. Am new to Kafka and streams. I know what I need to happen, just not the best way to get there. What else would you use to merge content from groups of topics into one table?

Comment: Spark? Flink? Nifi? You're not really merging anything. You're appending individual records into a single table, just happening to use a single consumer group